# Pytorch GRU Trained on one class to Predict Unlabelled Data

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, intrusion-detection, gated-recurrent-unit

I am creating a GRU to predict if data derived from traffic packets from a device is considered safe or anomalous. I plan to do this by training a model only on safe/ normal operating data and then having it check what it considers new unseen traffic to be (testing). I wish to only train on the safe data (one class) as an attack could take many forms and I don't want to train the model on labeled attack data and then have it miss an attack type that I didn't train it on (basically I want to overfit on the normal operating data). As such I need it to be able to check if the incoming unlabeled data matches the one class it has already trained on (i.e. does the incoming data match the normal operation of the device) or if it is anomalous.

The issue I am having is that as the model is being trained on only one class it is having trouble differentiating the anomalous unseen data from normal data and considers virtually all data that it sees as normal (same as the class it trained on).

As such I would appreciate it if anyone has any ideas or could point out flaws in the way I have implemented by model.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision  # torch package for vision related things
import torch.nn.functional as F  # Parameterless functions, like (some) activation functions
import torchvision.datasets as datasets  # Standard datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms  # Transformations we can perform on our dataset for augmentation
from torch import optim  # For optimizers like SGD, Adam, etc.
from torch import nn  # All neural network modules
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader  # Gives easier dataset managment by creating mini batches etc.
from tqdm import tqdm  # For a nice progress bar
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Hyperparameters
input_size = 24
hidden_size = 128
num_layers = 1
num_classes = 2
sequence_length = 1
learning_rate = 0.005
batch_size = 8
num_epochs = 5

# Recurrent neural network with GRU (many-to-one)
class RNN_GRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(RNN_GRU, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size * sequence_length, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Set initial hidden and cell states
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        # Forward propagate GRU
        out, _ = self.gru(x, h0)
        out = out[:, -1, :]

        # Decode the hidden state of the last time step
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

class MyDataset(Dataset):
 
  def __init__(self,file_name):
    stats_df=pd.read_csv(file_name)
 
    x=stats_df.iloc[:,0:24].values
    y=stats_df.iloc[:,24].values
 
    self.x_train=torch.tensor(x,dtype=torch.float32)
    self.y_train=torch.tensor(y,dtype=torch.float32)
 
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.y_train)
   
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    return self.x_train[idx],self.y_train[idx]

nomDs=MyDataset("nomStats.csv")
atkDs=MyDataset("atkStats.csv")
train_loader=DataLoader(dataset=nomDs,batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader=DataLoader(dataset=atkDs,batch_size=batch_size)

# Initialize network 
model = RNN_GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes).to(device)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train Network
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
        # Get data to cuda if possible
        data = data.to(device=device).squeeze(1)
        targets = targets.to(device=device)
        targets = targets.to(dtype=torch.long)

        # forward
        scores = model(data)
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)

        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # gradient descent update step/adam step
        optimizer.step()

# Check accuracy on training & test to see how good our model
def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0

    # Set model to eval
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for x, y in loader:
            x = x.to(device=device).squeeze(1)
            y = y.to(device=device)

            scores = model(x)
            _, predictions = scores.max(1)
            num_correct += (predictions == y).sum()
            num_samples += predictions.size(0)

    # Toggle model back to train
    model.train()
    return num_correct / num_samples

print(f"Accuracy on training set: {check_accuracy(train_loader, model)*100:.2f}%")
print(f"Accuracy on test set: {check_accuracy(test_loader, model)*100:.2f}%")
```